# Moving an ezPublish site

Tags: database, settings, move, ezpublish

I've never used ezPublish before, but I got the question if I could try to move a site. I found a forum post (http://share.ez.no/forums/install-configuration/moving-of-ez-publish-site-to-another-server) that explained how to do it. I had no errors during those steps, but my index.php is blank.

I also tried to add `die('Test')` on the first line of index.php, but got still a blank page. I think it's the database settings that does it, but it should be correct in `kickstarter.ini` (or is there any other places I need to update the database settings?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files had wrong permission set on them. Works now, but I have to figure out the user access levels.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about server access rights, try this (also assuming you are using a 4.x series of eZ Publish):

```
chown -R <user>.<usergroup> var/ settings/ design/ autoload/
chmod -R 770 var/ settings/ design/ autoload/
```